# Is the & necessary when referring to a member function

Tags: ruby

I was looking at ruby and the enumerable functions like [`inject`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject).  In the documentation, they state in the example that you can reference a member function with a colon followed by the name (e.g. `:+`).  However, I've seen other websites state that you should put a ampersand before the colon (e.g. `&:+`).  I'm just wondering, is that a change in the best practices?  If so, why the change?

Comment: The `&` is optional only for `inject`/`reduce`. It's a bit confusing that they implemented it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Using:

```
(5..10).inject(:+)
```

you're passing a symbol as a parameter, on the other hand using:

```
(5..10).inject(&:+)
```

[you're giving a proc as a parameter](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Proc.html#class-Proc-label-Conversion+of+other+objects+to+procs), which in other words, is like a shortcut for:

```
(5..10).inject { |sum, n| sum + n }
```

where the method `+` is called for the first `sum` parameter and the following parameters (as `n`) are just derived as parameters of `+`.
So, in general terms, this could be applied to any method that can handle procs and where the proc code is simple enough as to invoke a single method:

```
(5..10).map(&:to_s) # instead of (5..10).map {|n| n.to_s }
```

About what's the best practice, in general is suggested to use [the shorthand proc instead of the long version](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#single-action-blocks), but for the sole case you mention for the `.inject` method between `:+` and `&:+`, I think it's really up to you, as the method allow both parameters as valid.

Comment: I'll have to explore procs and lambdas more.  Ruby is certainly an interesting language.

Comment: Hmmm. So are you saying that when `:+` is used, in your example internally, if you were to unroll the operations, it uses (where `fn = :+`) `5.send(fn, 6).send(fn, 7).send(fn, 8).send(fn, 9).send(fn,10)`, but when `&:+` is used, then it uses `fn.call(10, fn.call(9, fn.call(8, fn.call(7, fn.call(6, fn.call(5))))))`?

Comment: I don't handle at all the inners of the [`.inject`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d92f09a5eea009fa28cd046e9d0eb698e3d94c5c/enum.c#L885-L926) method, but to me looks it's more like an iterative call than a functional one, for both cases.

Comment: Sorry, what I was asking is if this is what it would look like if the loop was unrolled.  This is a common practice in C++.